# How to assign a custom class to a sprite by default

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Is there any way I can make it so every time I add a particular image/sprite to the scene in the Scene Editor it can be assigned a Custom Class?

I am trying to make a game with a lot of sprites, and it is a hassle to assign Custom Classes to each sprite.

I know I can multi-select sprites and assign them the same Custom Class, but default Custom Classes would be so much easier.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do this

Comment: I haven't worked in Scene Editor, but when I need similar behavior in Interface Builder, I create a base "default" object and squirrel it away in a corner, then copy it and paste it into the xib/storyboard where I need it. Doesn't address all your issues, but it might be a useful workflow for you.